Save object with a RepeatedField (of grpc) in MongoDB
I am failed to save an object with repeated field in MongoDB.
There is no error, but the data is missing.
In my example below, i have class Message with a list of string called "lines" and a string field "sendTime".
When i save the object (message.lines is not null and have 3 lines of string), only sendTime is saved in database.
Can someone explain that and surguest a solution. Thanks!
in .proto file
service Messenger {
  rpc AddMessage(Message) returns (MessageRespone);
  rpc GetAllMessages(MessageRequest) returns (AllMessages);
  rpc DeleteAll(MessageRequest) returns (MessageRespone);
  rpc InsertMessageRepeated (Message) returns (MessageRespone);
}

message MessageRequest {    }
message AllMessages{
    repeated Message messages = 1;
}
message Message{
    string id = 3;
    string sendTime = 1;
    repeated string lines = 2;
}

message MessageRespone {
    string message = 1;
}

here is the service
private readonly IMongoCollection<Message> _messages;
 public MessengerService()
 { 
     Console.WriteLine("MessengerService is running " + DateTime.UtcNow);
     var Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
         .Build();
     var mongoConnection = Configuration.GetSection("Database:MongoConnection").Value;
     var databaseName = Configuration.GetSection("Database:Database").Value;
     var collectionName = Configuration.GetSection("Database:Collection_Test").Value;
     var client = new MongoClient(mongoConnection);
     var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
     //_messages = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
     _messages = database.GetCollection<Message>(collectionName);
 }

 public override Task<MessageRespone> AddMessage(Message message, ServerCallContext context)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Get message from client: " + message.Lines.Count);
     message.SendTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
     //BsonDocument bsonElements = message.ToBsonDocument();
     //Console.WriteLine(bsonElements);
     _messages?.InsertOne(message);

     return Task.FromResult(new MessageRespone { Message = "Messages saved successfully." });
 }

and here is the result

